# Make <h1> </h1> by C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, tags

I write This code in VS (C# and ASP.net) :

```
using (StreamWriter streamWriter = File.CreateText(@"Example.aspx"))
        {
                streamWriter.WriteLine( "<pre>" + TextBox2.Text + "</pre>"  );
            }
```

This code open the example.aspx file and write the value of TextBox2.text into Example.aspx .
but there is a problem . when i write `<h1> </h1>` into Textbox2.text i get error . or when i write `<i> </i>` into textbox2.text i get the same error !!! 
What am i going to do ? . Thanks in Advance . 
my error is :

```
A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$TextBox2="<h1> </h1>").
```

Comment: Are you claiming `<pre>` works, but `<h1>` or `<i>` don't work?

Comment: You are going to post that error here :)

Comment: I added a poor answer below since I misread the question, so I deleted it. What is the error (or exception) you get?

Comment: I edit my post and send my error . Tnx

Comment: So, what are you doing? Are you getting the error on the `WriteLine` line? Why are you creating an aspx file, anyway? How are you using it?

Answer (score 5):

The asp.net by default will block html code as input for a textbox, you must set in your page this attribute `ValidateRequest="false"` detailed example: http://yourtahir.wordpress.com/2008/03/28/aspnet-not-allow-html-in-text-boxserver-error-in-application-a-potentialy-dangerous-requestform-value-was-detected/

Comment: anyway my problem dosen't solved yet . i add ValidateRequest="false" in my @page file but i get same error . pls help me :(

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that ASP.NET filters dangerous requests (ones that contain characters such as `<` and `>`). You could disable this verification by putting `ValidateRequest="false"` at your @Page declaration. Of course if you do this you should make sure to fully understand the consequences as now your site is open to hackers. In this case user input is not sanitized and you should make sure to properly encode it if you decide to write it back on the page.

Comment: Isn't the OP writing to a file? (and an ASPX file, oddly). Seems a bit more complex than that, but good catch.

Comment: I add ValidateRequest ="false" in my @page but i get the same error !!! very strange !

Answer (score 0):

In addition to adding ValidateRequest="false" as Darin is suggesting you will need to add < httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" /> in your web.config inside the <system.web> section.